# Express using Pug: GET http://localhost:3004/contact 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am creating an app using Express.js and Pug as a view engine. It has a navigation bar redirecting the user to the 3 possible pages: *Homepage*, *Contact*, and *Our Services*.

---

The issue here is that only the homepage appears successfully. The rest of the pages (`contact.pug` and `our-services.pug`) show me the error: "GET http://localhost:3004/contact 404 (Not Found)", although the navbar does appear on top in each page.

I made sure that, for all pages:

1. There exists a js file in the routes folder that renders the page :

(`routes/contact.js`)

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var valid = require("../mychecker");
    
    router.get('/contact', function(req, res){
       if(valid()){
        res.render('contact', {
           name:"You can contact us here"
        });
       }
       else res.send("you are using this website outside working hours.");
     })
    
    module.exports = router;
```

2. The router of each page is imported into app.js and used using `app.use()`.
3. Every page can be accessed with the "buttons" present in `layout.pug`. It is the navbar that is included in every `page.pug` file.

I have tried to check any differences between my code for the homepage and my code for the contact and our-services page, and I did not notice anything different.

Here is my app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var homeRouter = require('./routes/homepage');
var contactRouter = require('./routes/contact');
var servicesRouter = require('./routes/our-services');

var app = express();

app.listen(3004, function(){
  console.log('Express listening on port', this.address().port);
});
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(['/','/home'], homeRouter);
app.use('/contact', contactRouter);
app.use('/our-services', servicesRouter);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});


module.exports = app;
```

This is my layout.pug file:

```
doctype html
html
  head
      style(type="text/css").
          nav {
              background-color: black;
              margin:0;
              padding:5px;
          }
          nav a{
              color:aliceblue;
              text-decoration: none;
              margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
          }

      nav
          ul 
                  a(href="home") Home              
                  a(href="our-services") Services              
                  a(href="contact") Contact 
  body
    block content
```

Finally, this is how every page.pug file looks like:
(`views/contact.pug`)

```
extends layout

block content
   body
      h1=name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a router file, importing, and using it in app.js, the route you provide here:

```
app.use('/contact', contactRouter);
```

Is used on top of your home route.
This means the link to the contact page is- HTTP://localhost:3004/contact/contact.
That is true for every router you've created.

if you want the page url to be localhost:3004/contact/ , you should change the statement as such:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
       if(valid()){
        res.render('contact', {
           name:"You can contact us here"
        });
       }
       else res.send("you are using this website outside working hours.");
     })
```